# List of <li>'s into two columns and with auto/equal width

Tags: css, multiple-columns

If I have a list of generated `<li>`s that I'm splitting into columns [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/HeyVian/kr9PE/) is it possible to somehow have the columns be only as wide as the widest `<li>`.

I have a drop down nav and currently I just had a fixed width on the `<li>`s but for smaller nav items like "FAQs" there is a lot of "empty space" that the client ask I remove.

The catch being that the code is generated for me so I can't add any additional markup. My experience tells me this isn't possible but I'd love if someone can prove me wrong.

Comment: are you open to javascript solutions?

Comment: @Brad Probably yeah. I personally don't think it's necessary but I'm trying to see what's possible.

Comment: per your comment, you can't really say 'I'm twice as wide as half myself' so i don't think its possible with pure css....

Comment: @Brad Yeah I figured. Just wanted some confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/kr9PE/2/.

It loops through all `<li>` elements, saving the widest one's width. Then it applies that width (plus the padding on both sides) to all `<li>` elements.

```
var items = $('#attempt ul').children();
var widestItemWidth = 0;
var padding = 10;

items.each(function() {
    var thisItemWidth = $(this).width();

    console.log($(this));

    if (thisItemWidth > widestItemWidth) {
        widestItemWidth = thisItemWidth;
    }
});

items.css('width', widestItemWidth + padding + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS, make the `UL` twice as wide as the `LI` and use `float:left;` on the `LI`.

Comment: what if you don't know how wide the LI is going to be?

Comment: You can't really specify I'm twice as wide as half myself

Comment: You will need to specify the width of the UL, yes. The key to empty space is to style the A-tag, not the LI and us display:block on the A-tag.